# Autowired not working with Azure function

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-functions

[image]

I am quit new in Azure function.
I found it as a interesting topic.right now,I have already develped azure function and works fine.
BUT my story will not end here. In the Function Method, I am trying to Autowiring my Repository class in spring in order to access to my DB layer. 
but it gives me a null pointer exception. means that , "@Autowired" annotation is not working and not initiate my HotelController Class. 
Any Idea , why I am not able to get the instance in Azure function?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you please add the solution if you know about it

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at:

1. [spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure)

   > This project provides an adapter layer for a Spring Cloud Function application onto Azure. You can write an app with a single `@Bean` of type `Function` and it will be deployable in Azure if you get the JAR file laid out right.
   >
   > There is an `AzureSpringBootRequestHandler` which you must extend, and provide the input and output types as annotated method parameters (enabling Azure to inspect the class and create JSON bindings). The base class has two useful methods (`handleRequest` and `handleOutput`) to which you can delegate the actual function call, so mostly the function will only ever have one line.
2. And the [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure) that shows how to use it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Itay for your comment. just wondering to know that ,
is Serverless Azure function + Spring  , compatible with DB?
for instance , If I want to use MySQL DB as my Database , is it possible to work with Serverless Azure function?

Comment: I am not aware of such a limitation.